# TreeView Binding with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm attempting to create a TreeView with a specific structure. I know how to create a TreeView and Bind data with a HierarchicalDataTemplate however I am struggling with how to design my template correctly.

The information I want to display to the user will look like this:
ClassA
---ClassB
---ClassB
---ClassB
ClassA
---ClassB
---ClassB
ClassA
---ClassB

In other words - I'll have a collection of ClassA which I would see as being a:

```
public ObservableCollection<ClassA> ClassAItems
```

And I want ClassA to hold a collection of ClassB thus:

```
public ObserverableCollection<ClassB> ClassBItems
```

Any suggestions on how to get this set up?

Comment: I actually may have answered my own question. My solution (pending approval from you guys) is creating a TreeViewModel object which contains a Header, Tooltip and ObserverableCollection (for nodes). Now ClassA inherits TreeViewModel and creates a collection of ClassB which also inherits TreeViewModel. Now when I bind to "Header" or "Tooltip" regardless of whether it is ClassA or ClassB it finds the correct property from the base class TreeViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my own issue by using inheritance. I've created a base class that both ClassA and ClassB inherit which contains the Models/Header/Tooptip properties.